# node.js importing file as string using cwd()

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, import

I want to achieve something that would be the equivelant of

```js
import sqlstring from `${process.cwd()}/scripts/script.sql`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fs` and the provided read [methods](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to read the file, e.g.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const sqlString = fs.readFileSync(`${process.cwd()}/scripts/script.sql`).toString();
```

Or you do it asynchronously:

```
const sqlString = (await fs.promises.readFile(`${process.cwd()}/scripts/script.sql`)).toString();
```